# Static DataTable, como carregar?

Tags: c#, ado.net, combobox, datatable, static

Estou precisando criar um método, que quando o usuário logar no sistema, ao ser carregado o menu inicial, ele carregue um `Static DataTable`, para que eu possa utilizar futuramente o `DataTable`, para popular alguns `ComboBox`, sem ter a necessidade de ficar fazendo diversas conexões ao meu banco de dados.

Então criei um classe static:

```
public static class Paises
{
    private static DataTable _tablePais;

    public static DataTable Tablepais
    {
        get { return Paises._tablePais; }
        set { Paises._tablePais = value; }
    }
}
```

Também criei uma classe, para fazer a conexão ao meu banco da dados:

```
 class Consulta_pais
{
    conexao_bd conexao = new conexao_bd();

    public void consulta()
    {
        conexao.bd_string();
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conexao.sqlconn);

        try
        {
            conexao._sql = @"SELECT code,descricao FROM Paises";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(conexao._sql, sqlconn);

            sqlconn.Open();

            Paises.Tablepais.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            sqlconn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

E então no load do menu inicial, chamo minha classe para trazer as informaçoes do banco:

```
 private void Menu_Inicial_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Consulta_pais load_pais = new Consulta_pais();
        load_pais.consulta();
    }
```

Porém, quando vou utilizar para popular um combobox, o mesmo fica em branco, estou populando o combobox assim:

```
 private void carrega_cb_pais()
    {
        comboBox5.DataSource = Paises.Tablepais;
        comboBox5.ValueMember = "code";
        comboBox5.DisplayMember = "descricao";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seguinte coloque a linha que preenche o combo depois de informar os value e display member

```
private void carrega_cb_pais()
    {

        comboBox5.ValueMember = "code";
        comboBox5.DisplayMember = "descricao";
        comboBox5.DataSource = Paises.Tablepais;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas Eric Pimentel, estava olhando seu código e acredito que na classe que você popula o DataTable _tablePais, não precisa passar o nome da classe na frente do objeto, porque eles estão no mesmo contexto. Eu refiz com algumas modificações e ficou assim:

```
public static class Paises
{
    private static DataTable _tablePais;

    public static DataTable Tablepais
    {
        get { return _tablePais; }
        private set { _tablePais = value; }
    }
}
```

Como você está só populando seu DataTable dentro da classe Paises, deixei o set como privado para não correr o risco desse DataTable receber valor fora da classe que foi declarado, e também para utilizar os conceitos de encapsulamento.

Criei um exemplo da classe de conexão com o banco de dados. Segue o exemplo:

```
public class conexao_bd
{
    private SqlConnection sqlconn;

    public SqlConnection bd_string(out string pstrMsg)
    {
        pstrMsg = default(String);

        try
        {
            // Conexão definida no no arquvio App.Config da aplicação
            sqlconn= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NOME_DA_CONEXAO"].ConnectionString);

            if (sqlconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                sqlconn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            pstrMsg = string.Format("Erro no método 'bd_string'\nDetalhes: {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return sqlconn;
    }
}
```

O método de consulta montei um exemplo, acredito que assim fica mais enxuto o código:

```
public class Consulta_pais
{
    conexao_bd conexao = new conexao_bd();

    public void consulta()
    {
        string strMsg = default(String);

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlconn = conexao.bd_string(out strMsg))
            {
                string strComando = @"SELECT code, descricao FROM Paises";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strComando, sqlconn))
                {
                    Paises.Tablepais.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Tratamento da exceção
        }
    }
}
```

Acredito que o Load do menu inicial, não terá problemas em carregar a combobox, eu deixaria da forma que você fez.

```
private void Menu_Inicial_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Consulta_pais load_pais = new Consulta_pais();
    load_pais.consulta();
}
```

E no final, para carregar a combobox faria assim:

```
private void carrega_cb_pais()
{
    comboBox5.ValueMember = "code";
    comboBox5.DisplayMember = "descricao";
    comboBox5.DataSource = Paises.Tablepais;
    comboBox5.Update();
    comboBox5.Refresh();
}
```